# Heredoc is not preserving text literally as I'm told it should

Tags: php, heredoc

I've just started the O'Reilly book on PHP, MySQL and JavaScript and I've just got to the stage where I learn about heredocs. It says in the book they preserve text literally, however mine doesn't at all. I've even copied the code exactly as it is in the book and it's still not behaving and I'm told it should.

I want my code to preserve the linebreaks within the heredoc but it just doesn't want to, the only way I can get it to do so is to use the "`< br />`" tag.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$author = "Bobby McBobson";

$text = <<<_END
This is a Headline.

This is the first line.
This is the second line.
- Written by $author.
_END

echo $text;
?>
```

No matter what variation of the code I use it always comes out like so:

```
This is a Headline. This is the first line. This is the second. -Written by Bobby McBobson
```

Whereas I'd like it to come out as:

```
This is a Headline.

This is the first line.
<br/>This is the second.
<br/>-Written by Bobby McBobson
```

Even on here I've had to use the `< br />` tag (broken up for obvious reasons), so I'm thinking there's something fundamental I'm missing?

Comment: HEREDOC's don't add html formatting.  View the source of the page, it looks correct there ;)

Comment: I'd just wrap them in paragraphs and style with css.

Comment: Do you need to do `echo "$text";` as would be necessary in a shell?  Alternatively, if you're using a browser to display HTML, then you have to include `<br>` tags (or a suitable variant) to get line breaks into the right places.

Comment: Or do `echo "<pre>$text</pre>";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line breaks are preserved but, when written as HTML, those line breaks lose their meaning; to add formatting in HTML you should use `nl2br()`:

```
echo nl2br($text);
```

You could also wrap them inside `<pre>` or some other tag that has the `white-space: pre;` style.

Comment: I guess I'll stop trying to coach someone how to make a good answer. =]

Comment: Came across the same issue when reading the same book... a perfect answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$author = "Bobby McBobson";

$text = <<<_END
This is a Headline.<br /><br />

This is the first line.<br />
This is the second line.<br />
- Written by $author.<br />
_END;

echo $text;
?>
```

works fine for me, don't forget the semicolon after END to close the variable $text definition. You really need the `<br />` tags if you want a new line otherwise it will just interpret as text.
EDIT: Actually the code without HTML stays formatted when I try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ but loses its formatting on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Not sure why?

Comment: I just added <br /> tags to create line breaks (<br /> is the HTML tag for new line) I also put the semicolon to end the variable definition

Comment: I know why you added the `<br />`'s in there, but you should explain _in your answer_ why you did it, and why what the OP thinks should work isn't working how they expect it to.

Comment: Ok Jon, is that what you meant?

Comment: I've just tried your original code in php sandbox (with a semicolon) and it keeps the formatting withouth having to add HTML...

Comment: Not quite - because you don't want it like that if inserted in to a DB, or if using the command line.  The explanation should be something leading to the fact that it is being viewed through a web browser.  For example, if enclosed in `<pre>` tags, it would show just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is quoted from the book.  It's a page or so further on.

> Laying out text over multiple lines is usually just a convenience to
>   make your PHP code easier to read, because once it is displayed in a
>   web page, HTML formatting rules take over and whitespace is suppressed
>   (but $author is still replaced with the variable’s value). So, for
>   example, if you load these multiline output examples into a browser
>   they will not display over several lines, because all browsers treat
>   newlines just like spaces. However, if you use the browser’s view
>   source feature, you will find that the newlines are correctly placed,
>   and the output does appear over several lines.